# How to use gsub to keep only the first characters/numbers in a vector in R?

Tags: r

Basically, I'd like to keep only the first character in a vector, I know this can be done in substr() easily, but I'd like to know how to do it in gsub().

For example,

```
codes <- c("02Q","4E (1)","4S (1)","A0","A2","A4")
```

I want a result vector like

```
c("0","4","4","A","A","A")
```

Thanks

Comment: I think this is just the classical XY question. If you have an easy and efficient solution, why are trying to overcomplicate it? I'd bet `substr(codes, 1L, 1L)` and surely `.Internal(substr(codes, 1L, 1L))` will beat any regex by both speed an simplicity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do

```
sub("^(\\w).*$", "\\1", codes)
#[1] "0" "4" "4" "A" "A" "A"
```

**Explanation:**

- ^: means the start of the string
- \w: means an alphanumeric item, which you captures with the brackets, and then retrieve by putting "\\1" as the replacement parameter
- .*: means anything, 0 or more times
- $: means the end of the string

Comment: Side note: `\w` is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, including the underscore in allowed chars. For only alphanumeric chars `[:alnum:]` would be better

Comment: @Tensibai, good point but what can be in the first "character" of the string is a bit vogue (I thought it was for digits only but you can have a letter so why not _ ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Seems you did like to keep only the first character.

```
gsub("(?<!^).", "", codes, perl=TRUE)
# [1] "0" "4" "4" "A" "A" "A"
```

`(?<!^)` negative lookbehind which asserts that the match would be preceeded by any but not the start of a line boundary.

**or**

```
codes <- c("02Q","4E (1)","4S (1)","A0","A2","A4")
sub("(?<!^).*", "", codes, perl=T)
[1] "0" "4" "4" "A" "A" "A"
```

Few more..

```
> sub("(?!^.).*", "", codes, perl=T)
[1] "0" "4" "4" "A" "A" "A"
> sub("\\B.*", "", codes, perl=T)
[1] "0" "4" "4" "A" "A" "A"
```